# Communication Between ESP8266-01 and NUCLEO-F030R8

Tags: stm32, esp8266, stm32cubeide

I've been tasked with figuring out how to get a mobile app to communicate with an MCU then in turn control a stepper motor. Right now I'm trying to get the WiFi module (ESP8266-01) and MCU (NUCLEO-F030R8) to play nice with each other. The catch is I have little to no experience and no education in this field. The closest experience I have is simple Arduino sketches from years ago (IE photo-resistor values driving a stepper motor) and making desktop applications with C#. I am using STM32CubeIDE but if there's a better option I can switch to that.

What I would very much like help on is **send and receive simple data between a smartphone and the MCU via the WiFi module**. I've read through documentation and other questions but still don't exactly know where to start.

I understand this is probably a large topic in its own right and a short blurb on the internet won't do it (and undoubtedly its multiple subcategories) justice. But I might as well ask.

Sorry if this is too much and thank you in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow is more dedicated to help answering specific technical questions related to development. Your issue is too broad to answer it here. Moreover it sounds like a complicated project and it might be a bit too much if you are a beginner in embedded software development learning on your own.

Comment: As a starting point I would suggest that you look at STMicro example projects that are provided with STM32CubeIDE. For example if your WIFI module (I don't know how it works) it connected to the Nucleo through SPI, open one of the SPI example project in STM32CubeIDE. You can learn how it must be configured and then modify the configuration to fit your WIFI module. Then you have to understand the protocol to manage the WIFI module: as a first step there are probably simple commands like "get status" or whatever (again, I don't know anything about this WIFI module, this is just an example)

Comment: the esp-01 is TTL UART and has AT firmware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project would involve making the following connections.

1. The UART connection between STM32 and ESP8266.
2. The WiFi connection between ESP8266 and the mobile.
3. The application layer protocol between ESP8266 and the application running on the mobile.

For 1, you can actually program the ESP8266 using Arduino IDE and simply connect the UART TX/RX pins of ESP8266 with RX/TX pins of STM32 respectively. You can create a test project in which ESP8266 sends data to STM32 over UART to verify this connection.

For 2, you need to consider the wifi network mode i.e identify whether the wifi connection is going to be ad-hoc (mobile connects to ESP8266 directly) or in infrastructure mode (mobile and ESP8266 connected via a shared access point). You can configure the ESP8266 in both modes. You just have to program the SSID and password of the Wifi network in the ESP8266 (in case of ad-hoc, it is the SSID of the network advertised by ESP8266 and in the infrastructure mode, it is the SSID of the common AP). This wifi functionality is also easily programmable in Arduino IDE for ESP8266.

Finally, once the physical connection has been established between the ESP8266 and mobile device, you need an application-level protocol to connect the application running on the mobile with the ESP8266. You can either use socket connection between ESP8266 and mobile application or use a higher-level communication protocol for IoT devices like MQTT, which is also available in the Arduino IDE.

Final connection diagram could be something like this:

```
application -> mqtt msgs -> wifi packets -> esp8266 recv pkts -> parse mqtt msgs -> forward data to STM32 over UART
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I've been working on getting the ESP and micro-controller to talk via UART (HAL drivers) but I haven't been able confirm a connection between the two. I'm aiming to put it in AP mode, so it can be directly connected to via the mobile app.